# Array in PHP Concatenation

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-1.3

i am trying to generate dynamic array as

```
foreach($this->data['Carcase'] as $key=> $value)
   {
    if(!empty($value))
    $data[$key]=$value;
   }
```

and got output as

```
array(
        $data['Hieght'] => 5,
        $data['Width'] =>6
     )
```

But i need output as

```
 array(
            $data['Hieght'] >= => 5,
            $data['Width']  >= =>6
       )
```

i tried this

```
foreach($this->data['Carcase'] as $key=> $value)
       {
        if(!empty($value))
        $data[$key].">=".=$value;
       }
```

this is not Working.Anybody have an Idea About this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel : Read Question Carefully , i already mention 
 array(
            $data['Hieght'] >= => 5,
            $data['Width']  >= =>6
       )

Comment: Your array is built just fine. What you have is a display problem, and your final chunk of code is NOT how you would go about solving it.

Comment: I can assure you, I read it carefully. Twice.

Comment: There's only a key and a value. You can't save a third element in this pair. If you want to insert `>=` anywhere in there, you need to concatenate it to the key or the value. What's the end goal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you want to concatenate the string ">=" to each key if the value is not empty:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($this->data['Carcase'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value) {
        $data[$key . ' >='] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: my bet that he's just like the `>==>` arrows more

Comment: My bet would be that he's trying to formulate a conditions array for CakePHP, in which case it would actually make sense (*gasp*).

Comment: @deceze : yes you are right i need Conditions array for Cakephp.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: hope you understand why i need this :P